# Where does this argument come from?

Tags: python, kivy

**Edit: Apparently I'm not very clear. I really don't know what's happening, so I didn't know what to ask for specifically. My question is how nap gets its argument, while I didn't specify one. Inclement understood what I meant, so I guess this is answered now.**

This might be stupid but I really don't understand where the "nap" argument for update (in "update") comes from. Edit: (Where it receives it's value from, is what I mean).

"Update" is only called from (edit: passed through) "on_start", nowhere else.

```
class ClockApp(App):
    sw_started = False
    sw_seconds = 0

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0)

    def update(self, nap):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.sw_seconds += nap

        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')

        m, s = divmod(self.sw_seconds, 60)
        self.root.ids.stopwatch.text = (u'{0:02d}:{1:02d}.[size=40]{2:02d}[/size]'
                                        .format(int(m), int(s), int(s * 100 % 100)))

    def start_stop(self):
        self.root.ids.start_stop.text = 'Start' if self.sw_started else 'Stop'
        self.sw_started = not self.sw_started

    def reset(self):
        if self.sw_started:
            self.root.ids.start_stop.text = 'Start'
            self.sw_started = False

        self.sw_seconds = 0
```

Comment: `update` is not "called" in `on_start`. It's just passed into the function. It's called in `schedule_interval` or passed into another function and called there. This is where `nap` is passed in.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't understand where `nap` is coming from? I don't understand your question. You are indeed passing `self.update`, to a function as a parameter, but you're not actually calling it

Comment: as already pointed, `self.update` is passed as an argument to `schedule_interval`. You need check the `schedule_interval` method to see how the method `self.update` gets called from there.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear about this. I'm relatively new to python and programming. I don't understand where "nap" is receiving its value from when the schedule_interval() thing is executed.

Comment: Unfortunately, we would need the code (or at least the docs) for `Clock.schedule_interval` to answer that correctly. It might be that the second argument (in this case `0`) is passed to `update`, but it's just as likely to be anything else.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear - the original poster doesn't understand why the update method receives an argument given that he didn't manually specify one, and the answer is that (as has been said) it is called internally by the Clock at which point it automatically includes this argument.

Comment: @inclement That is exactly what happenend. Thanks for making it clear!

Comment: @AustinMullins The code and docs for `Clock.schedule_once` are readily available online (https://github.com/kivy/kivy and http://kivy.org/docs). There is nothing unclear about this question, we just have people who don't know anything about Kivy deciding whether the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` is not directly called, but scheduled with the Clock via `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0)`. This automatically passes an argument to the function corresponding to the time since it was last called, which is what is called `nap` in this example.

Since the time between calls is set to `0`, the function will be called every frame and `nap` should end up being about 1/60.

For comparison, if you changed it to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)`, you would find that `nap` is always approximately 1...but not exactly 1, due to small (or if the main thread is blocked, large) fluctuations in when frames are pushed.

Comment: This is it! I've never seen a function recieve a argument from the very object it is put into (don't know if I'm saying it right).

Further question if you don't mind responding: How does this work? I've never seen this "flow". How can something recieve an argument when it is an argument to another function or class itself?

Comment: Now that I think about it: Is "0" the initial argument, but it gets changed by clock into something new (according to the delay from clock) before the actual update part itself is actually executed?

Comment: There is no initial argument. The important thing is that the function is itself an object that you can pass around - it is *not* called in your line of code, but the function itself is passed as an argument. This is totally general, for instance you could do `import math; a = [math.sin, math.cos]; a[1](5)` to calculate cos(5).